# Getting console log or geckodriver.log for remote firefox browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, saucelabs

Using below configuration as capabilities for the remote firefox browser(saucelabs)-

```
12:34:32.312 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "firefox",
  "moz:firefoxOptions": {
    "profile": "Test1",
    "prefs": {
      "devtools.chrome.enabled": false,
      "media.webrtc.hw.h264.enabled": true,
      "media.peerconnection.ice.tcp": true,
      "dom.webnotifications.enabled": false,
      "media.gmp-manager.updateEnabled": true,
      "devtools.console.stdout.content": true,
      "media.getusermedia.screensharing.enabled": true,
      "devtools.debugger.remote-enabled": true,
      "media.peerconnection.video.h264_enabled": true,
      "marionette": true,
      "media.navigator.permission.disabled": true,
      "devtools.debugger.prompt-connection": false,
      "media.navigator.streams.fake": true
    },
    "log": {
      "level": "trace"
    },
    "args": [
      "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream",
      "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream",
      "--start-maximized",
      "--disable-web-security",
      "enable-logging",
      "-start-debugger-server",
      "9222"
    ]
  },
  "selenium:webdriver.remote.quietExceptions": false
}
```

Yet unable to get the console info into the selenium-driver.log in saucelabs. Even setting the option "devtools.console.stdout.content": true also not yielding any file with geckodriver.log.
With the same settings, chrome console logs are being captured as part of selenium-driver.log. Is there anything to be configured for getting console output for remote firefox?
Any input on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: You just can't get the console in Firefox.
Please, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192232/selenium-trying-to-get-firefox-console-logs-results-in-webdrivererror-http-me